# JS: i++ and how it works

Tags: javascript, operators, increment, decrement

I've started learning Javascript about a week ago and for now I'm struggling with prefix and postifx increments. Can somebody please explain to me why in this code:

```
let i = 0;  
const x = i++;  
console.log(x);  
console.log(i);
```

Why in this code after executing console.log(i); it's 1 and not 0?
console.log(x); outputs to 0 and I think I know why, but I really can't understand the logic behind the value of i.
Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: What reference material are you using to learn JavaScript? This is fairly basic behavior and in fact is common to many languages related by a common tradition.

Comment: @Pointy, I'm learning mostly from youtube and W3, it's my first programming language, maybe that's the reason why I can't really understand this.

Comment: I know there's a really good older question out there but I'm terrible at finding duplicates. I can type in an answer, but you may want to look into something like the "You Don't Know JS" series of online books and other similar resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you used `i++`. If your code was

```js
let i = 0;  
const x = i+1;  
console.log(x);  
console.log(i);
```

Then `console.log(i)` would output 0 because `i = 0`
Now, the increment operator `++` increments the value of the variable by one, but it depends on the placement. 
When you did `const x = i++` it translated to assign `x` the value of `i` then increment `i` by one, if you would have done `const x = ++i` then `console.log(x)` would output 1, same for `console.log(i)`. Read [this](https://codeburst.io/javascript-increment-and-decrement-8c223858d5ed) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The "increment" operators date back at least to the C programming language of the 70s, and the basic idea of extracting a value from storage either before or after incrementing or decrementing is something from low-level computer architecture.

For both increment (adding 1) and decrement (subtracting 1), there are two variations. The *pre-increment* and *pre-decrement* operations, where the `++` or `--` comes before the variable, are easier to understand: the value in the variable is changed, and then the result is the new value.

The *post-increment* and *post-decrement* operations are strange because the value you get is the value as it was *before* adding or subtracting 1. The value in the variable afterwards is still changed as with pre-increment or decrement, but the value *in the context* is the value before the change.

Thus:

```
var x = 0;
console.log(++x); // logs 1, pre-increment
console.log(x--); // also logs 1, post-decrement
console.log(x);   // logs 0, because of the decrement
```